# How to mock task.isSuccessful google.android.gms.tasks?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

Need to mock response but for some reason does not import correctly. So how to mock that

```
package com.google.android.gms.tasks;

    public abstract class Task<TResult> {
        public Task() {
        }

        public abstract boolean isComplete();

        public abstract boolean isSuccessful();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure that I understand your question. But if you're trying to wrap something that uses the firebase tasks, like remote config, you may have to make your own implementation of Task. For example something like:

```
override fun loadConfig(onSuccess: () -> Unit, onFailure: () -> Unit) {
        firebaseRemoteConfig.fetchAndActivate().addOnCompleteListener() { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    onSuccess()
                } else {
                    onFailure()
                }
            }
    }
```

Then in order to test it you would have to create your own implementation of Task, rather than use a mock like:

```
class TestTask(private val isSuccess: Boolean) : Task<Boolean>() {
    override fun addOnFailureListener(p0: OnFailureListener): Task<Boolean> {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    ....

    override fun addOnCompleteListener(p0: OnCompleteListener<Boolean>): Task<Boolean> {
        p0.onComplete(this)
        return TestTask(isSuccess)
    }

    override fun addOnCompleteListener(
        p0: Activity,
        p1: OnCompleteListener<Boolean>
    ): Task<Boolean> {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    ...

    override fun isSuccessful(): Boolean {
        return this.isSuccess
    }
}
```

Then you can test your class calling the remote config like:

```
    @Test
    fun `should return success callback when successfully loading config`() {
        every { firebaseRemoteConfig.fetchAndActivate() } returns TestTask(true)
        var testReachedCallbackBlock = false

        testSubject.loadConfig(
            onSuccess = {
                testReachedCallbackBlock = true
            },
            onFailure = {}
        )

        assertTrue(testReachedCallbackBlock)
    }
```